# PHP Error : Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: arrays, php

Can't seem to see what's the problem in this one, 
Should be simple but i seem to be witless.

```
    if(empty(search($class,'id',$p_cid))){
     unset($categories[$elementKey]);
 }
```

search function returns an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be this way:

```
$arr = search($class, 'id', $p_cid);
if (empty($arr)) {
    unset($categories[$elementKey]);
}
```

Comment: Ya, This solved it. Cheers m8

Comment: mark his response as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> **Note:**
>
> **empty()** only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: **empty(trim($name))**.

Try this:

```
$tmpVar = search($class, 'id', $p_cid);
if(empty($tmpVar)) {
  unset($categories[$elementKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)).

Answer (score 0):

A far as I know, the empty function works only on variables, not return values. So, try this:

```
$s = search($class,'id',$p_cid);
if(empty($s)){
  unset($categories[$elementKey]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

search isn't a function in PHP. Array_search is.

Comment: `function search($foo,$bar,$baz) {}` Oh look, now it is. But you're right that the OP should have posted the relevant part of own code.

Comment: I disagree, because i knew the problem isn't there and i'm missing a small thing =/